# Is there a syntax for wildcard export as?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, syntax

There is the import syntax:

```
import * as foo from 'bar';
```

I similarly tried:

```
export * as foo from 'bar';
```

but that threw the errors:

> ```
> ERROR in src/app/@theme/components/aComp/aComp.loader.ts(1,10): error TS1005: 'from' expected.
> src/app/@theme/components/aComp/aComp.loader.ts(1,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> src/app/@theme/components/aComp/aComp.loader.ts(1,17): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> src/app/@theme/components/aComp/aComp.loader.ts(1,22): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> ```

there is also the export syntax:

```
export { default as foo } from 'bar';
```

Is there a way to do this for `*` as opposed to `default`?

---

(FYI I'm trying to remove `require` from the statement):

```
export const foo = require('bar');
```

the error below is thrown when `ng serve` is run including the `.ts` above:

> ```
> ERROR in src/app/@theme/components/aComp/aComp.loader.ts(6,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
> ```

Comment: What exactly would an `export * as foo` do? How exactly would that `require` line work without `require`?

Comment: How about using `import * as foo from 'bar'; export foo;`

Comment: @deceze I don't have much idea. I'm just trying to remove `require` as tslint bugs me about it.

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher That does work indeed. Wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: Then perhaps tell us how tslint bugs you about it and ask us what to do about that. See http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: @deceze I understand, included the error message above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is not, but there is [a proposal to add this syntax to the language](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from).

Currently, you will need to use

```
import * as foo from 'bar';
export { foo }; // verbose: { foo as foo }
```

which is actually even closer to `export const foo = require('bar');` than `export * as foo from 'bar';`, as it does provide `foo` in the local module scope as well.

Comment: Thanks. Does this account for `const` as well?

Comment: @Nae You mean the `const` in `const foo = require('bar');`? Yes, the imported namespace object is immutable.